# Autofill missing row in database based on missing time range

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have a table in Postgresql database which store a datetime along with some integer that look like this:

```
      dt                total                                                   
--------------------------------                                        
2019-07-01 10:00:00     150                                      
2019-07-01 10:15:00     153                                      
2019-07-01 10:30:00     155                                      
2019-07-01 10:45:00     160                                      
2019-07-01 11:00:00     161                                   
....
```

As you can see that datetime in dt column will be in 15 minutes range consecutively. My question here is that, there might be sometime that incoming data missed some row.

For example:

```
     dt                total                                                   
--------------------------------                                        
2019-07-01 10:00:00     150                                      
2019-07-01 10:15:00     153                                      
2019-07-01 10:30:00     155                                      
2019-07-01 10:45:00     160                                      
2019-07-01 11:00:00     161
2019-07-01 11:15:00     163
2019-07-01 12:00:00     170
```

From this example, there are n=2 missing rows which are row of time 11:30 and 11:45. What I wanted to do here is to autofill datetime of those rows and use average from the total column of the last row before missing row (11:15) and the first row after missing row (12:00) as a total for each missing row

For this example, each missing row's total column will be add by (170-163)/(n+1) = 7/3 = 2.333 (let use 3 decimal digit here) So the result will become like this:

```
     dt                total                                                   
--------------------------------                                        
2019-07-01 10:00:00     150                                      
2019-07-01 10:15:00     153                                      
2019-07-01 10:30:00     155                                      
2019-07-01 10:45:00     160                                      
2019-07-01 11:00:00     161
2019-07-01 11:15:00     163
2019-07-01 11:30:00     165.333
2019-07-01 11:45:00     167.666
2019-07-01 12:00:00     170
```

I think it cannot be done directly with SQL. So, I think Python might help solving this purpose. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `generate_series()` and some math.  The following assumes that `total` is increasing (as in your sample data):

```
select d.dt, seqnum,
       coalesce(t.total,
                (max(t.total) over (order by d.dt asc) +
                 (min(t.total) over (order by d.dt desc) - 
                  max(t.total) over (order by d.dt asc)
                 ) *
                 (seqnum - max(seqnum) filter (where t.total is not null) over (order by d.dt asc)) /
                  nullif(min(seqnum) filter (where t.total is not null) over (order by d.dt desc) -
                         max(seqnum) filter (where t.total is not null) over (order by d.dt asc),
                         0
                        )
                 )
                )
from (select dt, count(*) over (order by dt) as seqnum
      from (select generate_series(min(dt), max(dt), interval '15 minute') as dt
            from t
            ) d
     ) d left join
     t
     on t.dt = d.dt;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=aed9bc9dc91b84073ebd88f63cabe616) is a db<>fiddle.

The calculation is just cumbersome because you need to do a weighted average to get the in-between values.  The formula is:

```
prev_value + (next_value - previous_value) * ratio
```

and the ratio is:

```
(current_time - prev_time) / (next_time - prev_time)
```

But instead of times, this uses a sequential count.

Comment: After adding ' after 15 minute and deleting one bracket before max(seqnum. I got this error `column reference "dt" is ambiguous
LINE 3:                 (max(total) over (order by dt asc) +` so I added `d.` before it and got this `ERROR:  division by zero` instead

Comment: And I kinda confuse about your ratio formula and you give me some example on that?

Comment: Oh so I made a mistake, should add `t.` instead of `d.`. Result from this queryt generate missing date for me but not total value.

Comment: @Jamiewp . . . I fixed the small mistakes in the query and added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Sorry for replying late. I forgot that I need to have one another column for, let say type, which each type has it own datetime and total row. I am not sure this might be unclear for you, should I create a new question or just edit this question?

Comment: @Jamiewp . . . You should ask another question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57293718/autofill-missing-row-based-on-time-range-separately-for-each-type Your welcome

Comment: I correct min and max seqnum column in your shared fiddle. It should be `where t.total is not null` instead of `where t.total is null` to produce a correct variable to use formula of ratio